# Extract part of json file using Python in another json file

Tags: json, python-3.x, list

I want to extract part of an existing JSON file based on a list of keys and save it into another JSON file
For eg-

```
{
"211": {
        "year": "2020",
        "field": "chemistry"
    },
"51": {
        "year": "2019",
        "field":"physics"
},
"5": {
        "year": "2014",
        "field":"Literature"
}
```

Lets say the list =[5,51]

Output json file should contain

```
 {
    "5": {
            "year": "2014",
            "field":"Literature"
         },
    "51": {
            "year": "2019",
            "field":"physics"
           }
    }
```

}
It should not contain data for key 211

Comment: There is 10k+rows.Above one is just an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this will work for you:

```
import json

# Open input file and deserialize JSON to a dict
with open("input_file.json", "r", encoding="utf8") as read_file:
     input_file_dict = json.load(read_file)

# List of id's you want
inc_id_list = [5,51,2,101]

output_dict = dict()

# Iterate over the input file JSON and only add the items in the list
for id in input_file_dict.keys():
    if int(id) in inc_id_list:
        output_dict[id] = input_file_dict.get(id)

# Serialize output dict to JSON and write to output file 
with open('output_file.json', 'w') as output_json_file:
  json.dump(output_dict, output_json_file)
```

Comment: This cannot be used since there is no specific start and end id .Above one was an example.I have around 10k+ rows with different ids

Comment: If you meant it would be an arbitrary list of ids, not a range, then all that has to be done is change the if statement to "if int(id) in list"  I just update my code.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
l=  {
    "211": {
            "year": "2020",
            "field": "chemistry"
        },
    "51": {
            "year": "2019",
            "field":"physics"
    },
    "5": {
            "year": "2014",
            "field":"Literature"
    } }

    for i,v in l.items():
       if(i!="211"):
           print(i,v)
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution.But there are 10k+rows.Above one is just an example .It would be very difficult for me to generate a list of keys which are not required.Can you please suggest any other solution

Comment: Can we Place list of keys that are not required into another list  and say something like not in List l?

Answer (score 0):

It's a dictionary of JSON, with a missing bracket at the end, so that is easily done with a comprehension:

```
mydict = { "211": { "year": "2020", "field": "chemistry" }, "51": { "year": "2019", "field":"physics" }, "5": { "year": "2014", "field":"Literature" }}

incList = [5, 51]

myAnswer = {k:v for (k,v) in mydict.items() if int(k) in incList}
```